# Flexslider Nav button not working in hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

Okay, I'm using flexslider 2. I've used it plenty of times in my projects and have never had an issue before.

When I hover over the banner image the Next and Previous buttons should slide in but they do not. I am just using all the default functions nothing fancy. I can't find any issues in my code that would prevent flexslider from acting correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

The nav buttons are present and opacity is 0 by flexslider default css and should appear on hover but do not.

Project can been seen here:

http://madmen6raphics.com/clients/marble/index.html

Comment: Slider is working perfectly okay.Issue with nav buttons.Check out its default CSS and make sure path of nav button is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up flexslider.css and change the following

from

```
    .flexslider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 0.7; left: 10px; }
    .flexslider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 0.7; right: 10px; }
```

to

```
    .slider:hover .flex-prev { opacity: 0.7; left: 10px; }
    .slider:hover .flex-next { opacity: 0.7; right: 10px; }
```

Comment: Man... how could I over look that. I completly forgot that default class for that is .flexslider. Thanks a bunch @SamirAlley